# List Datasheet view track who changed an element

Tags: list, user

I want to know who changed a value in a list datasheet view row.  The list is created by exporting, from Excel to Sharepoint, a 400 row table.  Many users come to the list and enter two values in the rows that pertain to them.  For auditing purposes would want to know who made those changes. I haven't been able to find anything that addresses tracking who made changes to individual rows in datasheet view using normal sharepoint tools/features.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn versioning on for a specific list.  Go to `List Settings` -> `Versioning Settings`.  From here you can turn `Item version history` on.  With this you can see the changes between versions and also in those setting determine how far back you want to keep the history for, in terms of versions.

If you don't want something that specific you can use the `Modified By` field which is on a list by default.  As well as `Modified` so you can see the time it was last changed.  This doesn't give you what specifically was changed however.